# Create directory from files and move files

Tags: files, directory, mv

I want to move files based on a specific pattern. I was working with this code, but it does not work well with the task.

```
for file in *.fastq.gz
do
 dir="${file%R*}"
 mkdir -- "$dir"
 mv -- "$file" "$dir"
done
```

These are some examples of files:

```
121123_SN323_A_L002_GPS-100_R1.fastq.gz
121123_SN323_A_L002_GPS-100_R2.fastq.gz
130201_SN132_B_L007_GPS-100_R1.fastq.gz
130201_SN132_B_L007_GPS-100_R2.fastq.gz

121123_SN323_A_L002_GPS-104_R1.fastq.gz
121123_SN323_A_L002_GPS-104_R2.fastq.gz
130201_SN132_B_L007_GPS-104_R1.fastq.gz
130201_SN132_B_L007_GPS-104_R2.fastq.gz
```

So with these files, I just want to create two folders, `GPS100` and `GPS104`.
But I get 4 folders with the code above, namely:

```
121123_SN323_A_L002_GPS-100_
121123_SN323_A_L002_GPS-104_
130201_SN132_B_L007_GPS-100_
130201_SN132_B_L007_GPS-104_
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to strip off the front of `$dir` with `dir=GPS${dir#*GPS}`.

The resulting script:

```
$ ls
121123_SN323_A_L002_GPS-100_R1.fastq.gz
121123_SN323_A_L002_GPS-100_R2.fastq.gz
121123_SN323_A_L002_GPS-104_R1.fastq.gz
121123_SN323_A_L002_GPS-104_R2.fastq.gz
130201_SN132_B_L007_GPS-100_R1.fastq.gz
130201_SN132_B_L007_GPS-100_R2.fastq.gz
130201_SN132_B_L007_GPS-104_R1.fastq.gz
130201_SN132_B_L007_GPS-104_R2.fastq.gz

$ for a in *.fastq.gz
do
  dir=${a%_R*}
  dir=GPS${dir#*_GPS}
  mkdir -- "$dir" 2>/dev/null
  mv -i "./$a" "$dir/"
done

$ ls
GPS-100/  GPS-104/

$ ls *
GPS-100:
121123_SN323_A_L002_GPS-100_R1.fastq.gz
121123_SN323_A_L002_GPS-100_R2.fastq.gz
130201_SN132_B_L007_GPS-100_R1.fastq.gz
130201_SN132_B_L007_GPS-100_R2.fastq.gz

GPS-104:
121123_SN323_A_L002_GPS-104_R1.fastq.gz
121123_SN323_A_L002_GPS-104_R2.fastq.gz
130201_SN132_B_L007_GPS-104_R1.fastq.gz
130201_SN132_B_L007_GPS-104_R2.fastq.gz
```